# How to make GET request with MERN Stack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

I'm trying to fetch data from database. Everything I got from response is this:

```
Response {type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:5000/products/", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
```

I need help for how to make the request in frontend and backend:

Here is ReactJS side:

```
getProducts() {
        fetch('http://localhost:5000/products/', {
            method: "GET",
        })
        .then(response => console.log(response))
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data)
            this.setState({products: response.data});
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    }
```

Here is my server side for the request:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    productService.getAll(req.query).then(products =>{
        res.status(200).json(products)
    }).catch(() => res.status(500).end())
})
```

Here is the productService:

```
async function getAll(query) {
    let products = await Product.find({}).lean()

    return products;
}
```

P.s.: the products are creating without errors in MongoDB Compass:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call [`response.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) to extract the JSON body from the response stream and return it to the next `then` block in the chain. And you can omit the `method` configuration since it is `GET` by default.

```js
fetch('http://localhost:5000/products/')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((products) => {
    this.setState({ products })
  })
```

---

Btw, you shouldn't hardcode the API URL. Use environment variables. If you're using [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/), you can [add environment variables prefixed with `REACT_APP_` to `.env`](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env) or you can use [dotenv-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack) if you have a custom Webpack setup.

```js
fetch(`${process.env.BASE_API_URL}/products`)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((products) => {
    this.setState({ products })
  })
```

Comment: Thanks, you almost solved it. And I had to remove the ".data" :D Thank you

Comment: @YoanIvanov My bad. Just updated the answer.